# Need to include MA in ARMA

Tags: regression, time-series, arima

An AR(1) process can be defined as-

$\begin{aligned}
Y_t=\mu+\phi Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t=\mu[\frac{1-\phi^t}{1-\phi}]+\phi^t Y_0+\sum_{i=1}^t\phi^{t-i}\epsilon_i
\end{aligned}$

Clearly the above implies that an AR(1) can be thought of as MA($q\rightarrow\infty$) where MA($q=1$) is the moving-average process defined as-

$Y_t=\mu+\epsilon_t+\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}$

In light of this, why do we include the MA in ARMA models when the lagged residual terms have already been captured in the AR process? Is it just the fact that the coefficients have been constrained to be a power of $\phi$ in AR, and an actual MA would do better to describe them?

Comment: It takes an infinite AR to completely capture an MA(q) (and an infinite MA to completely capture an AR(p)). So an ARMA(1,1) has only a few parameters, but modelling it adequately as an AR or an MA alone could require a large number of parameters.